# How to force developers to use a specific commit message

Tags: git, npm, cross-platform, git-husky

Our product documentation tells our developers to run `git config commmit.template .gitmessage`. However, many developers have not done so and are not following our commit template.

I'm using the following husky hook to stop a commit if they haven't set `commit.template`.

```
"husky": {
    "hooks": {
        "pre-commit": "if `git config commit.template` | grep -q '.gitmessage'; then lint-staged; else echo 'Commit template not being used. Please run git config commit.template .gitmessage' && exit -1; fi"
    }
},
```

However, I get the following error when running it on Windows.

```
> if `git config commit.template` | grep -q '.gitmessage'; then lint-staged; else echo 'Commit template                                             not being used. Please run git config commit.template .gitmessage' && exit -1; fi

config was unexpected at this time.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! gittest@1.0.0 gitcommit: `if `git config commit.template` | grep -q '.gitmessage'; then lint-st                                            aged; else echo 'Commit template not being used. Please run git config commit.template .gitmessage' && e                                            xit -1; fi`
```

Is there an approach I can take that works for both Windows and Unix?

Comment: Can you clarify what "does not work for Windows" means? Do people get an error message, is the check skipped entirely?

Comment: @WanderNauta Added the error message from Windows